# Intuitive Meaning of Integral Dependence

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

I've recently came across the notion of a Ring $B$ being integral over a subring $A$. Atiyah-MacDonald (at least the few pages right after the definition) refrain from explaining the intuitive interpretation of the definition.

Why do we define the "integral ring over" relationship?

Does this relationship captures some important properties of the "naive" ring of integers  $\mathbb{Z}$?  Maybe properties of the relationship with other rings $\mathbb{Z}$ is traditionally embedded in?

What are those properties?

Comment: Integral means "locally" finite in the sense that an integral extension is a union of finite extensions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @LukasHeger. Would you be kind enough to spell it out for me? Why does being a union of finite extensions deserve the adjective "integral"? Why do you double quote the word "locally" in your comment?

Comment: In commutative algebra, locally can refer to other things, namely localisation. The original motivation comes from algebraic number theory, where the integral closure of the integers in a number field plays a similar role to the integers.

Comment: In addition, being integrally closed is related to being regular in codimension 1, see Serre's criterion for normality.

Comment: Thanks again @LukasHeger. About the "role of the integers" - I'm not sure I understand what is this role. If you're willing, I would greatly appreciate some more details. An introductory-flavor example could be extremely helpful. About Serre's criterion - I'll look it up. Many thanks!